# What HTTP status code should the old VirtualHost return after a migration

Tags: domain-name-system, http, migration

We have moved a website from a server to another.

DNS was updated appropriately, but some servers do not honor TTL, and some places may have the old server's IP hardcoded.

How should I inform them that the VirtualHost is no longer here?

Is there an appropriate HTTP status code for that (maybe 503)?

If it's not HTTP's responsibility, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP status code 301 is used to indicate that a site has permanently moved to a new location according to [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3) (500 series usually indicate server errors) however, redirects typically use a URL/DNS hostname to redirect. If your issue is just one of TTL, using a 301 is not going to work unless you have both a new IP *and* a new URL too. In fact, using a 301 redirect will break web traffic to your site as the user's browser will just keep redirecting over and over to the same place, never loading a webpage.

Simply put, you are going to have to encourage people to be RFC compliant in their DNS implementations and honor TTLs and simply wait out the caching. Once you are sure the caches are expired and have updated, you are going to have to reach out to all of those hard-coding IPs and have them update or (preferred) use DNS.

Otherwise, you may want to splash a maintenance page informing the user of the issue and asking them to contact their IT department to report the problem.

Comment: What should the maintenance page HTTP status code be then?

Comment: Wouldn't a 503 be more appropriate for such a maintenance page?

Comment: 503 is better than 200, because 200 implies that the page content is OK, which causes search engine bots to actually index that content. 503 is the correct indicator of the site being temporary unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to avoid site availability issue during TTL period for A records is to implement a reverse proxy in your old server, which relays requests to the new server. This way people that end up to the old server, will get the page from the new server.

If your site uses client IP addresses for something, then you need to configure old site reverse proxy to add an HTTP header with the client IP address and configure new site to use the IP address from the HTTP header as the client's IP address.

Comment: That's a good practice. However I am not trying to deal with TTL issues here. I am specifically asking for the best way to inform the client that it should update it's configuration in case it has not taken the migration into account.

Comment: There isn't really any configuration the client could update here. Only thing that needs updating are DNS entries, and DNS has its own mechanisms for updating domain zone entries, which are completely independent of the actual HTTP server the web page uses.

Comment: I was not thinking about browsers but rather firewalls or reverse-proxies, that may not rely on DNS and have the old IP in their configuration. Thanks for your comments, I will stick to a maintenance page with a 503.

Comment: There is no mechanism to notify any such devices of such changes. The firewalls and reverse-proxies need to be configured with the new information. Furthermore, having such a mechanism would open many security holes, and therefore the mechanism would do more harm than good.